# Doxygen not recognize PHP Class in static array storage

Tags: php, class, static, doxygen, factory

In my PHP project im using a Class factory that stores the object instances inside an object member of a static class. This member is an array and if for example i gonne instance lib/log.php (class log {....) it will be accessed like

```
glob::$data["lib/log"]
```

Since im using this structure all over my project i want doxygen to recognize the calls for the call/caller graphs and for linking the functions. In my code i currently do like

```
glob::$data["lib/log"]->info("info to log.......");
```

Wich i realized wont be recognized by doxygen so i tried modify the code to structure like:

```
$libLog = glob::$data["lib/log"];
$libLog->info("info to log......");
```

And adding source comments to tell the code wich instances of classes im using here. I tried in both ways like

```
/* @var $libLog log */
```

same as

```
/* @var log $libLog */
```

since i found examples refering to both of that. None of them worked. The log class itself gets recognized and is inside the Class list so it can't be an recognation error.

If anyone has idea how i can make doxygen recognize those calls or a hint to another stack posting that solves this problem i would be really gratefull!

Comment: Didn't try it but as far as I know, by head, you should use for doxygen not /* but /**

Comment: Tried that too didn't work , even tried to use \ instead of @ prefix since its the default of doxygen, didn't help either. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You also write something, in the header, about static. Did you look at the EXTRACT_STATIC in the doxygen configuration file? Other wise post a small complete example to show the problem including the changes to the standard doxygen configuration file.

Comment: Yes EXTRACT_STATIC is enabled. Im in another office currently but as soon im back to the other office i gonne differ my config to the default one and post the changes as requested.

Comment: Not yet in the other office ( ;-) ), I now se /* with only one *, this should be /** I think